# How to disable response decompression in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, compression, response

I need to disable response compression. I have .NET 4.5 version of web.config but I need in .NET Core 2.x now.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <httpsTransport decompressionEnabled="false" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I have web service which is not support compressed response and I am still get error:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type application/x-gzip of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 653 bytes of the response were: '?'

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core has [documentation on compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.1). As you can see, ASP.NET Core no longer uses web.config. If you're hosting your ASP.NET Core app in IIS, then some web.config settings are still used, but only those relevant to generic IIS hosting, nothing application specific (dynamic compression is an IIS feature, so that setting is still relevant, but other web.config settings that used to be relevent in ASP.NET apps are no longer used in ASP.NET Core). Unfortunately I can't find documentation at the moment as to which web.config settings are still relevant.

Anyway, ASP.NET Core by default uses the Kestrel web server, which is configured in code. Making a small modification to the sample in the documentation I linked above, I beleive this might work:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        var gzip = options.Providers.OfType<GzipCompressionProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (gzip != null)
        {
            options.Providers.Remove(gzip);
        }
    });
}
```

But it depends where the compression is coming from. If you have a reverse proxy between your ASP.NET Core app and the internet (for example IIS, but maybe nginx, haproxy, etc) they might be doing compression, so you need to understand your application architecture and turn it off at the right place.

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler or Postman to verify that your app is not compressing output when running locally?

Comment: I've been playing around for a bit and it seems like ASP.NET Core does not compress output, unless you explicitly configure it like the docs say. You should still verify yourself that your ASP.NET Core app isn't doing output compression, but I'm pretty sure you'll need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that with this tools.

Comment: I tried to change urlCompression and httpCompression in IIS Express but without success.

Comment: One think, web.config is support by ASP.NET Core. So I think I have to setup WCF like in .NET 4.5

Comment: When I created a new ASP.NET Core app from the new project template, it did not use output compression. I can't help you any more without a [MCVE sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test myself.

Comment: Also, I recommend changing your debug options to debug your app stand-alone first, and if you verify it works as expected, then run it in IIS Express. Fewer pieces to test makes it easier to isolate the problem.

Comment: Try to start application without IIS Express, still same problem. So it is not caused by IIS Express. I was googling and I discover that DecompressionEnabled was supported in .NET Framework 4.7.2 but not in .NET Core. I was try to find something in ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement but no success.

Comment: I now think there was a big misunderstanding. .NET Core doesn't appear to support WCF as a service, only WCF clients. This means your ASP.NET Core app is using WCF services, not providing WCF services. This means you need to configure the WCF server to stop using output compression, not this app. Or, look into changing the WCF client to accept compressed input. My answer and this entire comment thread is completely off-topic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am coding client side, server side is not mine so I cannot setup anything. Server is not using output compression. I get an error above. So I need change DecompressionEnabled. But where.. it is not supported by .net core.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.httpstransportbindingelement?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Actually, the error message is telling you the opposite. The server is responding with application/x-gzip, but your client is expecting text/xml. You need to configure your client to accept compressed responses. I suggest deleting this question and doing some searches. Ask a new question if you can't figure out how to do it, but the question is asking for the wrong thing.

Comment: I think that this is not right. My client send to service Accept-Headers: gzip,deflate and service is send gzip to me. So I need stop sending Accept-Headers:gzip, deflate from my side. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: If you create a new question and use the words you used in that comment, you're more likely to get a good answer. Just mention you want to do this with a .NET Core WCF client. The words you used in your question is confusing and makes it unlikely that WCF expert will look at your question.