# Final message in server events not being pushed until heartbeat

Tags: c#, servicestack

We are having an issue with the final message sent over service stack waiting until the next heart beat to be sent. We believe it to be similar to :

[Servicestack server sent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960723/servicestack-server-sent-events/25983774)

However, res.Write() is now deprecated and res.WriteAsync() throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed after the response has been submitted
```

I have also tried to solve the issue stated in the above thread by using  :

```cs
// Remove url compression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559038/asp-net-core-disable-response-decompression
// because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960723/servicestack-server-sent-events
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    var gzip = options.Providers.OfType<GzipCompressionProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (gzip != null)
    {
       options.Providers.Remove(gzip);
    }
});
```

Would appreciate a push in the correct direction to addressing this issue as the currently accepted solution to this issue is no longer viable.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of ServiceStack? Sometimes simply updating the package can fix bugs.

Comment: Yes -  And if you see the "Servicestack server sent events", it's an issue with .net's flushing. The linked post is for a work around. Said work around is not depreciated.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest [ServiceStack v5.7](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.7) that was just released? If it's still an issue you can try to use the new [Server Events Async APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.7#server-events-async-apis).

Comment: Updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202564/serverevents-last-message-not-being-recieved-until-heartbeat