# ServerEvents - Last message not being recieved until heartbeat

Tags: c#, typescript, servicestack

Extension on : [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165887/final-message-in-server-events-not-being-pushed-until-heartbeat?noredirect=1#comment102721383_58165887)

We are having an issue where the last message sent over server events is not being revieved until the next heartbeat. The client in question is using the Service Stack [Typscript Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference)

Here is a stripped down implimentation of the [server setup / calls](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BzMdWt)

As suggested in the original post, we have upgraded to 5.7 *AND* switched over the the async api and it still waits for the next heartbeat.

The c# implimentation for a this works without the delay against the same server. Below is the relevant code from that :

```cs
public class Events
{
    public async Task Setup(string channel)
    {
       _client = new ServerEventsClient(_baseUri.ToString(), channel);
       _client.OnJoin += OnJoin;
       _client.OnConnect += OnConnect;
       _client.OnCommand += OnCommand;
       _client.OnMessage += OnMessage;
       _client.OnException += OnException;
       _client.Start();
       _ = _client.Connect();
       //
       _log.Text = $"{DateTime.Now} : [Connected] : {channel.ToString()} \n {_log.Text}";
       // Wait to receive onJoin command event
       var joinMsg = await _client.WaitForNextCommand();
    }

    private void OnMessage(ServerEventMessage e)
    {
        AddToLog($"[Message Received] {e.Data}");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have something else either in your App (or external network if you're going through any middleware) buffering responses in your App. If this also happens locally can you publish a small/stand-alone App on GitHub I can download and run locally to repro the issue.

Comment: I don't have the code with me, but at one point to avoid the IIS buffering I used the `OnPublish` event to shove down 1024 bytes of spaces.  Bandwidth wasn't an issue for us (all local intranet), and this was circa SS 4.5.  I'm not sure how that'd work with async world though, but its *something* to try.

Comment: @mythz Created a stripped down version of our workflow and works locally and introduces lag only when it hits azure servers. Will update when discover the solution.